# Drive stepper motor using 2xAA NiMH 800mAh (2.4V)

Tags: stepper-motor

I am designing a circuit for driving the stepper motor, the link attached (https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3v-12mm-2-phase-micro-dc_60641420857.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.17.149a279bsYy1CA&s=p) using 2xAA (2.4V) NiMH 800mAh batteries. Also, I am using a boost converter U1V10F5 (0.5V-5.5V)to step up from 2.4V to 5V to power up the motor as well as the driver (DRV8834). I've found that the motor that runs at 2.7V consumes approximately 70mA. The question is if I am using normal 2xAA(3V) battery or bench power supply (set it to 2.7V) the circuit is working fine and the motor is running. Whenever I set the voltage to 2.6V or 2.4V on the bench power supply or connect the 2XAA rechargeable battery my motor stops working.

Is that the rechargeable battery not having enough capacity? or the step up booster is not able to supply enough current to drive the motor at 2.4V?
Please let me know why the motor is not running at 2.4V and runs at 2.7V. I have attached the rough schematic. I am using two PSU for the microcontroller(5V@3A) and the motor(2xAA(2.4V)) indicated in dotted lines in the schematic. Your guide is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIuqsB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: aren't there any capacitors on the output of your U1V10F5?

Comment: oh I see, they're already part of the package

Comment: I suspect that the series resistance of the loop AA-batteries to Boost converter and back (ground connection) has too much series resistance. How is this build up, on a breadboard? With connectors ? The series resistance that I mention must be **really** low otherwise the boost converter cannot extract enough energy from the batteries. The current into the boostconverter is about 150 mA on average but it will be pulsed. Those pulses can be up to 1 A. If too much voltage is dropped across connections then the inductor (in the converter) cannot charge properly and output current is limited.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for your help. I've built up in Vero board using the connector and bridged them using solder. Will that make any difference?

Comment: @BeB00 Thanks for your help. Yes, it is already built-in.

Comment: You have to try and see what works. You could add a large (220 uF - 470 uF) low ESR capacitor as close as possible to the input and ground of the upconverter. But, I do think that you expect a bit too much from these batteries + upconverter. Having 4 batteries in series without an upconverter would work much better I expect.

Comment: I have used already 100uF cap next to Vin and ground. Is that enough? The requirement is to use 2xAA and boost circuit. Unfortunately, I cannot 4 batteries. Just to let you know the circuit is working fine with 3XAA rechargeable batteries.

Comment: Buy, rent, borrow a scope and see....

Comment: Hi all I've managed to fix the motor to work with 2xAA rechargeable batteries. I've got a question now How to activate the motor rotator section just by clip-on action with the top section?(not using the on/off switch to turn the rotator on). Only I got is step signal line and direction signal line from the top section. Could anyone please suggest me with the solution/idea. Thanks